# Low Cost, 2 Ethernet Ports & Runs Linux

Tags: hardware, embedded, ethernet

Looking for an inexpensive embedded device that contains 2 Ethernet Ports, runs Linux (or some other type of Unix), and is under $50.

My main concern is cost. It must be under $50 and have 2 Ethernet ports.

It can be a bare circuit board, it doesn't need to be a complete device with cover and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://soekris.com/

Not at the $50 level, but probably what you're looking for in general.

Comment: That is quite nice but above $60 I cannot possibly use these in my project. I'll need about 2000 of them and customers won't be willing to pay about above $80 total.

Comment: @unixman83 You said you "cannot possibly use these" and then accepted the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at [OpenWRT's Table of Hardware](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) finding a supported router that is on that list that you can buy for less than $50 and then flashing the firmware with OpenWRT (Tomato and DD-WRT likely have similar lists )

Answer (score 1):

Buy a Raspberry Pi and a usb Ethernet adapter  ( they are about $5-$10 ) [ now you will have double ethernet ] so it will be lower than $50

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a Raspberry Pi (http://www.raspberrypi.org/)

It only has one ethernet port, but at half your specified price, you could purchase 2 to get the double ethernet port, effectively doubling the power of the system.

Comment: However, if you're looking to sell something to customers, you might want to get a specialised PCB to fit your requirements.

Comment: Related SE site :  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2):

Dlink or linksys with debian. minix also.!